# Perforce checkin without using editor

Tags: perforce

When I use p4 submit to checkin changes, an editor opens up and I enter a description of the change. I would like to know if it is possible to make the standard input the place where I enter the description. I am using Perforce in Linux.
 Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the "-d" flag:

```
p4 submit -d "My description"
```

You can also use "p4 submit -i", but this reads a complete changelist specification, not just the description.  Run "p4 change -o" to see what the changelist specification should have in it and where the description fits into it.  An equivalent to the above command using "change -o" and "submit -i" would be:

```
p4 change -o | sed -e "s/<.*>/My description/" | p4 submit -i
```